# How to make a floating/3D Touch style tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

So i'm making an application for tracking livestock. I have made a table view for the animals to go in. I have a navigation controller at the top with a button in side of it.[Here is what i have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lW85.png)

I would like to have a floating table view come up when the button is pressed similar to the 3D touch menu.
[Like these.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgx4Y.jpg)

My question is how would i go about doing this. Sorry if this is a commonly done thing im pretty new to swift and xcode

Comment: you can take a look into [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna to implement，you could search the key words as 'pop over', 'kxmenu' or 'menu' on GitHub/CocoaControls. such like this: https://github.com/zpz1237/NirKxMenu https://github.com/liufengting/FTPopOverMenu

Also, you should make it yourself. When the button is pressed, first you should create a custom window and make it key window. Secondly, add a tableView or a view contains tableView to the custom window. then, use block or delegate to deal with data communication and respond user interaction. After that, design animation you need. At last, remove subviews from custom window and make the original window key window.

Comment: Thanks a ton this was just what i was looking for!